# Java chat program which also sends file

Tags: java, file, sockets, chat, transfer

I have made a basic chat program which also sends, well its incomplete. Everything runs fine, except when I send a file, my program receives it without any problem, but it gives a socket closed error.

CLIENT

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class chatClnt {

    public static int PORT = 6666;
    public static String IP_ADDR = "192.168.15.1";
    public static String F = "FILE MODE";

    public static void main(String[] ar) {

        try {
            InetAddress ipAddress = InetAddress.getByName(IP_ADDR);

            System.out.println("\nconnecting......");
            Socket socket = new Socket(ipAddress, PORT);
            System.out.println("\nconnected");

            InputStream sin = socket.getInputStream();
            OutputStream sout = socket.getOutputStream();

            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(sin);
            DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(sout);

            BufferedReader keyboard = new BufferedReader(new         InputStreamReader(System.in));

            String line = null;
            String fname = null;

            while (true) {
                System.out.println("\nYou(Plain Text):>");
                line = keyboard.readLine();
                out.writeUTF(line);
                out.flush();
                if (line.equals(F)) {
                    //Sending File
                    OutputStream fout = socket.getOutputStream();
                    FileInputStream fis = null;
                    BufferedInputStream bis = null;
                    try {
                        System.out.println("Enter the path: ");
                        fname = keyboard.readLine();
                        File myFile = new File(fname);
                        byte[] mybytearray = new byte[(int)myFile.length()];
                        fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);
                        bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
                        bis.read(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);

                        fout = socket.getOutputStream();
                        System.out.println("Sending " + fname + "(" + mybytearray.length + " bytes)");
                        fout.write(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
                        fout.flush();
                        System.out.println("Done.");
                    } finally {
                        if (bis != null) bis.close();
                        if (fout != null) fout.close();
                    }


                    line = in.readUTF(); // wait for the server to send a line of text.
                    System.out.println("\nSender(Plain Text):> " + line);
                    System.out.println();
                }
            }
        } catch(Exception x) {
            x.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

SERVER

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;


public class chatSrv {

    public static int PORT = 6666;
    public static String F = "FILE MODE";
    public final static String FILE_TO_RECEIVE = "received.txt";
    public final static int FILE_SIZE = 999999999;

    public static void main(String[] ar) {

        try { 
            ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(PORT);
            System.out.println("\nconnecting...");
            Socket socket = ss.accept();

            System.out.println("\nconnected");
            System.out.println();

            InputStream sin = socket.getInputStream();
            OutputStream sout = socket.getOutputStream();

            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(sin);
            DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(sout);

            String line = null;
            int bytesRead;
            int current = 0;

            while (true) {
                line = in.readUTF();

                //Receiving File
                if (line.equals(F)) {
                    FileOutputStream fos = null;
                    BufferedOutputStream bos = null;
                    try {
                        byte [] mybytearray = new byte [FILE_SIZE];
                        fos = new FileOutputStream(FILE_TO_RECEIVE);
                        bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
                        bytesRead = sin.read(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
                        current = bytesRead;

                        do {
                            bytesRead = sin.read(mybytearray, current, (mybytearray.length-current));
                            if (bytesRead >= 0) current += bytesRead;
                        } while (bytesRead > -1);

                        bos.write(mybytearray, 0 , current);
                        bos.flush();
                        System.out.println("File " + FILE_TO_RECEIVE+ " downloaded (" + current + " bytes read)");
                    } finally {
                        if (fos != null) fos.close();
                        if (bos != null) bos.close();
                    }

                    System.out.println("\nSender(Plain Text):> " + line);
                    BufferedReader keyboard = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

                    System.out.println("\nYou(Plain Text):>");
                    line = keyboard.readLine();
                    out.writeUTF(line); 
                    out.flush(); 
                    System.out.println();
                }
            }
        } catch(Exception x) {
            x.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please post the actual error? Also minor coding style note, when you import try to import specific packages instead of `import java.net.*`. It's a good habit to have.

Comment: remove fout.close();, you are running the while loop forever and closing after receiving hte file once which means that after a single file the  stream is closed so it wont be able to read anymore data from that stream

Comment: on removing `f.out.close()` will hang the program as the file never gets closed

Answer (score 1):

When you close the output stream of a socket, this closes the socket as well. The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#getOutputStream%28%29) says:

> Closing the returned `OutputStream` will close the associated socket.

So you cannot close the stream. But if you don't close it, you'll never get `-1` on the receiving side.

So basically, you can't use the same reading procedure you use when you read a file from a disk. You need to devise a protocol that will allow you to read the file while still keeping the stream open. Possible strategies:

- Open a second socket for this. For example, open a socket on an available port, and send the server a message that it should connect to that other socket with this port number. Then you can send the whole file through that other socket and close it. Or ask the server to open a second socket and tell you which port number to connect to. This is the strategy used by the ftp protocol.
- Send the length of the file in bytes in advance, and on the receiving side, read that many bytes. This is the strategy used by HTTP, for example, when it sends the `Content-length:` header.

Remember that files can be very long, so if you decide to send the length, use `long` rather than `int`.

Comment: Pleas please help me little more precisely

Comment: If I don't close the `OutputStream` the program doesn't moves forward, what should I do

Comment: @SiddharthMazumdar As I said, you can't just decide not to close it - because you'll never get the -1 on the other end and it will just wait for more input. Instead, you should re-think your protocol, based on one of the strategies.